# Generate appropriate schema for object type using Swagger v3 annotations

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi

I'm struggling to generate a proper documentation using Swagger v3 annotations. The thing is that the project is quite legacy and we didn't generate it using Open API 3, so for now I'm trying to write a cool documentation using the annotations.

Consider this following example:

```java
@ApiResponse(description = "Displays the queried data",
  responseCode = "200",
  content = @Content(additionalPropertiesSchema = @Schema(implementation = CategorySchema.class)))
class DataDto {
  @Schema(title = "Data by category", 
    description = "Displays data grouped by the selected categories",
    additionalProperties = Schema.AdditionalPropertiesValue.USE_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_ANNOTATION)
  private Map<String, Data> dataByCategory;
}

@Schema(title = "Data", description = "A categorized data")
class Data {
  @Schema(title = "Model", description = "Model definition", example = "A")
  private String model;
  @Schema(title = "Name", description = "Registered name", example = "SOCIAL_NETWORK_DISCUSSION")
  private String name;
}

@Schema(title = "Category", description = "An example of a category schema")
class CategorySchema {
  @Schema(title = "Popular", description = "Some popular data")
  private Data popular;
}
```

My goal is to generate the following API docs:

```json
{
  ...,
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "DataDto": {
        ...,
        "properties": {
          "dataByCategory": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CategorySchema"
            }
          }
        },
        "CategorySchema": {...},
        "Data": {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the above, I could implement contract-based examples even if my response is supposed to be very generic. However, this is what I'm getting:

```json
{
  ...,
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "DataDto": {
        ...,
        "properties": {
          "dataByCategory": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Data"
            }
          }
        },
        "Data": {...} # CategorySchema isn't even created
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hence, my question is how to properly point which schema I want to represent the additional properties of an API response (or perhpaps request). Could you please help out?